# Llenar DataGridView C# desde una View de SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2017

He estado haciendo consultas `SELECT` en tablas de `SQL Server` y todo normal, pero hice una `View` para tener todo ordenado al hacer `LEFT JOIN`, pero al querer consultar la `View` me aparece el error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: no se ha inicializado la propiedad CommandText'
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer consultas a las `Views` o no?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas @Elian, sera necesario que cuelgas como el código de llamada a la View,  y un poco la definicion de la view. Saludos!

Comment: Podrias poner el código que estas usando, para tener una clara idea de lo que puede ser

Comment: Sería bueno que mostraras tu sección de código y mas detalles, por lo que medio se logra ver es que te tira un error de ExecuteNonQuery , si lo que quieres es llenar un dataGridView creo que el ExecuteNonQuery no te dará lo que buscas, necesitas un ExecuteReader, hay mucha documentación al respecto, ojalá puedas apoyarnos compartiendo más información.